# Tkinter treeview string with space issue

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

When i print datas from a MySQL table on a Tkinter treeview , if the data which is a string contains space , it divide the string into two strings .this make desordre in the treeview , the first new string on a column , and the new second string on the next column of the treeview which is reserved for an other string . here is the code how i print data from the MySQL table on the treeview .`rows = cur.fetchall()

```
if rows :      
    for z in rows:

                print z[0],z[1],z[2],z[3],z[4],z[5]
                tv.insert("","end", values=("%s %s %s"%(z[1],z[2],str(z[3]))))
                #tv.insert("","end", values=("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s"%(z[1], z[2],str(z[3]),z[4],z[5],z[6],z[7],z[8],z[9])))
```

cur.close()`

Comment: check this link to undertsand `https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve`

Answer (score 0):

the issue is solved withe the method replace() , this could print data in order , but I just want the string z[3] be printed with its spaces . Here is the new code : `tv.insert("","end", values=("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s"%(z[1], z[2],z[3].replace(" ","-"),z[4],z[5],z[6],z[7],z[8],z[9])))` .
  This replace spaces with "-" .

Answer (score 0):

`ttk.Treeview` seems to split a given string by spaces to multiple values.

If you don't like this behaviour you have to pass the value as a tuple.

So instead of

```py
tv.insert('', 'end', text='foo', values=('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'))
```

you should write

```py
tv.insert('', 'end', text='foo', values=('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', ))
```